# Can I use a variable in an ajax error call instead of the Function name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax call that works fine, but I am now trying to polish the code a bit

```
                $.ajax({
                url: wbURL,
                dataType: "xml",
                contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
                type: "POST",
                headers: '@"HEADER DATA',
                data: dataPacket,

                success: dealWithResonse,

                error: dealWithError
            });
```

what I am now trying to do is replace the success and error function names with variables so I can use it for other jobs.

```
var SuccessFunctionCall =  dealWithResonse;                      
var ErrorFunctionCall = dealWithError;

                $.ajax({
                url: wbURL,
                dataType: "xml",
                contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
                type: "POST",
                headers: '@"HEADER DATA',
                data: dataPacket,

                success: SuccessFunctionCall,

                error: ErrorFunctionCall
            });
```

But my program stops at this point, assumingly as it can't find a function called
ErrorFunctionCall.

can I use a variables vaule instead of an actual function name?

Thank you in  advance

Comment: seems fine to me, can you post the relevant error message?

Comment: Should work, but I am thinking we need to see more code. What is the error in the console?

Comment: I don't understand, you can already use `dealWithResonse` elsewhere. Why introduce a new variable that points to an existing one?

Comment: Both your code part does the same. Anyway, for your question, the answer is YES

Comment: `var ErrorFunctionCall = funcction dealWithError(){ // Your code };`

Comment: Hi @epascarello , there is no error, it just stops (assuming it's because it cannot locate the function.

Comment: If there is an error, than it would show up in your console unless the page is refreshing and clearing the console. Still think we need to see more context so we can help you figure it out. As it is written above, it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may define those functions as global and assign them to what you want:

```
var SuccessFunctionCall = function(){dealWithResonse()};
var ErrorFunctionCall = function(){dealWithError()};
```

and call them as members of window:

```
success: window[SuccessFunctionCall](),
error: window[ErrorFunctionCall]()
```

Finally I have to say that I am not sure why you want to assign functions to variable names. You may define those functions directly and call them as you need.

Comment: Hello, What I have is similar code being used in serval places. I am trying to create a global function, which I can then pass specifics to (like, what to do on an error etc)  The Functions are already in place and work,I just wanted to pass the "correct" one as a variable  eg         function ClickAgain(ButtonToChange, errorRoutine) {
            /* Click Listener */
                  $('.' + ButtonToChange).click(function () {.....                     error: errorRoutine

Comment: OK. the code I suggested is the only way to work with variable (say string) instead of functions. @GeraldOakham

Answer (score 0):

You should define those functions in your variables as shown below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var SuccessFunctionCall =  function dealWithResonse(){
  console.log("success");
};                      
var ErrorFunctionCall = function dealWithError(){
  console.log("error");
};

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http:test',
    dataType: "xml",
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    type: "POST",
    headers: '@"HEADER DATA',
    data: '',

    success: SuccessFunctionCall,

    error: ErrorFunctionCall
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Try this